dynamic imports in NextJS v14.2.3 leads to the Hydration error
I was updating NextJS from v13 to v14 and got a Hydration error because of dynamic imports.
Are there options to fix it?
const MyComponent = dynamic(() => import('../components/MyComponent'))

Is there a solution that allows both lazy loading and SSR rendering?
I found 2 solutions:

Get rid of dynamic imports:
import MyComponent from '../components/MyComponent'
Disable SSR:
const MyComponent = dynamic(() => import('../components/MyComponent'), { ssr: false })


Server components cannot be loaded using dynamic()
Server Components by definition, are "bundle-less", meaning that they are rendered server side, and no JS bundle is ever made for them.
Why are you importing them dynamically, when even if you import it, the client will not see any change in the bundle?
Check this discussion out for more information -
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/51016

thank for your answer, what discussion do you have in mind?

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

@IhorFesina added the relevant GitHub discussion
